# How to pass requirements.txt parameter in Dataflow when Dataflow is being triggered by Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

**Objective-** I have a dataflow template **(written in python)** that has a dependency on pandas and nltk also I want to trigger the dataflow job from cloud function. For this purpose, I have uploaded the code to a bucket and I am ready to specify the template location in the cloud function.

**Problem-** How to pass the requirements_file parameter that you would normally pass to install any third-party library when you trigger a dataflow job using the discovery google module from cloud function?

**Prerequisites-** I know this can be done when you are launching a job through the local machine by specifying a local directory path but when I try to specify the path from GCS such as `--requirements_file gs://bucket/requirements.txt` it gives me an error saying:

> The file gs://bucket/requirements.txt cannot be found. It was specified in the --requirements_file command line option.

Comment: Have you deployed the Google Cloud Function how you would normally do via `gcloud functions deploy`? Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python#specifying_dependencies) which is a quickstart and shows how to specify dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, it mentions requirements.txt for google-cloud-function and not google-dataflow isn't it?

Comment: OK I'm getting a little confused then. So you have a Google Cloud Function which you want to use to trigger a Cloud Dataflow pipeline, correct? How does that function look like?

Comment: doc- https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates
code- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/dataflow/run_template/main.py

Comment: I was just about to ask, does it work if you trigger it via `gcloud dataflow jobs run`?

Comment: Yes, it works when all the parameters are given including the --requirements_file parameter.

Comment: Not sure if you need to reference your `requirements.txt` on the bucket, I think you can just do a relative reference to your template location, I guess something like `--requirements_file ./requirements.txt` and it should find it on the bucket.

Comment: When you create and stage your pipeline, one of the flags should be `--requirements_file requirements.txt \`. Remember that the requirements.txt must be in the same bucket as the template. On the other hand, if you are running it locally, according to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/), you should use the commands ` pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then when executing the pipeline `--requirements_file requirements.txt`. Did it help you?

Comment: I had tried this before, even added the requirement.txt in the bucket as well as created a new in the cloud function machine, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template of dataflow is not a python or java code instead it is a compiled version of the code that you've written in the python or java. So, when you're creating your template you may pass your `requirements.txt` in the arguments like you normally do as shown below

```
python dataflow-using-cf.py \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project <PROJECT_ID> \
    --staging_location gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/staging \
    --temp_location gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/temp \
    --template_location ./template1 \
    --requirements_file ./requirements.txt \
```

The above command will create a file with name `template1` which if you read, contains a JSON structure, this file is a compiled version of the Dataflow code that you've written and during the compilation process, it will read your `requirements.txt` from your local directory and compile its steps. You may then add your template to a bucket and provide the path to the cloud function, you don't have to worry about the `requirements.txt` file after creating a template.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this. Now it's working.